# How does GCC behave if passed conflicting compiler flags?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I know that if you execute GCC as such:

```
gcc -O3 -O2 foo.c
```

GCC will use the last optimization flag passed (in this case `O2`). However, is this true for all flags? For example, if I execute GCC like so:

```
gcc -mno-sse -msse bar.c
```

Will it support SSE since that was the last flag passed, or would this result in undefined behavior? My initial experimentation seems to indicate that it will support SSE, but I'm not sure if this is true for all cases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Normally later options on the line override ones passed previously, as you mention in your first example.  I haven't personally come across any different behaviour for `-m` or `-f` flags, but I don't know of a specific reference in the documentation.

Note that some options don't behave this way:

```
$ gcc example.c -DABC -DABC=12
<command-line>: warning: "ABC" redefined
<command-line>: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
```

So there would need to be a `-UABC` in between there to shut that warning up.

As an aside, `clang` is particularly good at solving this problem - it will produce a warning if it ignores a command line option, which can help you out.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that gcc still behaves in the "later options on the line override ones passed previously" way, even in your example. It's just that it *also* gives you a warning.

Comment: `main(){return 0;}` will compile silently with no flags, and will produce `warning: return type defaults to ‘int’` when called with `-std=c99 -Wno-implicit-int -Wno-implicit`, in every order possible.

Comment: [The docs for warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) do say ("_The combined effect of positive and negative forms is that more specific options have priority over less specific ones, independently of their position in the command-line. For options of the same specificity, the last one takes effect._"), but not the optimization or other options docs. However, you can inspect the final options list that is used to compile by using [`-frecord-gcc-switches`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html), which will show that the last one is used.