# If you specify conflicting command line arguments to GCC, which one is accepted?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have a makefile that compiles C++ files with a rule rather like this:

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(FILE) $(DEFINE) $(INCLUDE) $(USER_CXXFLAGS)"
```

For a particular configuration of the build system, `$(CXXFLAGS)` includes the value `-O2`.  But, I can add my own flags to `$(USER_CXXFLAGS)`,  and for easier debugging want to add `-O0`.  The end result of this is that when compilation is done, the compiler command line will include multiple conflicting instructions about how to optimize.

Which one does it use?  I suspect it's reasonable to assume that the last specified option takes precedence, but given that position matters for some G++ options I don't want to make that assumption.  Is this behavior documented somewhere? I read the man pages but was unable to find any specification about repeated options in general.

Comment: [same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909788)

Comment: AFAICR, the de facto mode of operation is the 'last takes precedence' when you work with things like `-std=c99` vs `-std=gnu11`, so I would expect the same to apply to other options such as `-O`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `-O0` option has taken effect over the previous `-O2` but I'll still welcome anyone who quotes whatever deeply buried documentation states that this is true in all cases.

Comment: @DrewDormann i would say this is actually a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Ben You're not alone.  :)

Comment: I don't know how I didn't find the other question given that it's title was basically exactly the same as this one's, and I spent at least 10 minutes googling for it... :(

Comment: @Wug the beauty of crowdsourcing.

Comment: Curious...my Google search on 'gcc conflicting arguments' turns the other question up as the top answer.  I don't know if I've got Google particularly well trained or...well, you must have used a different query, I suppose.