# How do I change default compiler flags in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, gcc, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 4.5.2 on ubuntu.

For example, in release mode the default optimization flag is -O2, how can I change it to -O3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241567/qmake-how-to-remove-compiler-flag-for-a-certain-project-without-changing-qmake

Comment: @atomSmasher - thanks, it did help :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your .pro file, you can add below:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += O3
```

Comment: have tried that but it just adds the -O3 to the -O2, isn't this kind of a conflict? 
see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909788/how-does-gcc-behave-if-passed-conflicting-compiler-flags

Answer (score 0):

According to the post by atomSmasher the solution was:

1. for c files

`QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE = $$replace(QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE,"-O2","-O3")`

2. for cpp files

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = $$replace(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE,"-O2","-O3")`