# -std=c++14 after -std=c++11 in my build command, which wins?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have both options on in my Makefile, Basically, my Make file looks like this

```
$OPT_FLAG := -O2 -std=c++11 $CXXFLAG += $(OPT_FLAG) -std=c++14
```

so actual build command is sth like

```
g++ -m64 ... -std=c++11, -std=c++14 ...
```

and of course `$CXXFLAG` is passed as argument to invoke gcc build. In this case, am I using c++14 or c++11?
my gcc version is 5.4

Comment: IIRC it is the rightmost option that is chosen.  Trying to find a dupe target

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909788/how-does-gcc-behave-if-passed-conflicting-compiler-flags

Comment: i added another duplicate, it is about `-Ox` but still I thought it is related enough to add it

Comment: Is there more to this than checking what `__cplusplus` is, and checking if it's consistent depending on the order you pass?